# Why I don't see User Custom Attributes in AWS Cognito service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am using AWS Cognito service and I added to my users in User Pool custom attributes, and check the custom attribute check box in the App clients -> Show Details -> Set attribute read and write permissions, However when I run the command "aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id XXXXXX --username XXXXXX" in AWS cli I get all user attributes except the custom attributes that I added.

I building android app but I get the same result in the code.

So my question is how to get the user custom attributes?

Comment: Are you sure the custom attributes have values? If you log in as the user, is the custom attribute available in the `idToken`?